# How to write a sentence properly when three or four incidents occurred in the past?

Tags: tense, past-tense

For example:

> I knew he had worked in the company for five years before he got a promotion.

> Someone worked for a company for five years. After that, he got a promotion. I knew about it.

> We knew he thought the patient had died before the doctor came.

> At first, the patient died. Then the doctor came. Someone thought about this incident. We knew someone thought about it.

Are my sentences grammatically correct? **How to maintain the sequence of tense? Which tense structure should I follow?**

Comment: *We knew he thought the patient had died before the doctor came* could have multiple meanings. Maybe we were aware before the doctor's arrival of what he thought. Maybe ***he*** was under the impression the patient was dead, until the doctor arrived and started treating him. Maybe the patient was definitely dead, but *killed by the doctor* (whereas he mistakenly thought death occurred before the doctor even showed up). There are probably other interpretations, but that's enough to make the point.

Comment: (The point being that if you string several different elements together like this, there's a significant chance the ***relationships between those elements*** may end up being "uncertain, open to interpretation", thereby creating ambiguity.)

Answer (score 1):

> I knew he had worked in the company for five years before he got a promotion.

> We knew he thought the patient had died before the doctor came.

Your first example correctly describes the sequence of events.

You may want to modify your second example to

> We knew he thought [about the event in which] the patient had died before the doctor came.

Comment: Are both of my sentences grammatically correct? I actually want to know which structure should I follow to write this kind of situation?

Comment: Your second example is also grammatical but has a different meaning from the set of events it is trying to describe.  '...he thought the patient had died...' means the patient had not died.

Answer (score 0):

It should be chronology ordered and context of who what where why is of relevance.

Someone worked for a company for five years. After that, he got a promotion. I knew about it.

Who is someone, what is the company?

So for example with a little bit more pertinent information the sentence would read like.....

I was aware that (Mr. Jane Doe) had worked for (generic company name) for five years prior to receiving (his current promotion) or (a promotion).

At first, the patient died. Then the doctor came. Someone (WHO IS SOMEONE)thought about this incident. We knew someone thought about it (THOUGHT ABOUT WHAT AND WHO IS WE)

The doctor arrived after the patient had passed away. The nurse was aware of this situation. The nurse and I were aware that the situation was being addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your sentences are grammatically correct.
Your first sentence is correct and natural-sounding.

Your second sentence might not completely match the meaning of the event. I would write it like this:

(casual)

"We knew he(or she, or someone) thought about how the patient died before the doctor came."

OR(most formal)

"We knew he(or she, or someone) thought about the patient's death before the doctor's arrival."